# How can I exclude a file on Azure Devops in the Deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I apologize for my english, im using a translator.

I need make a deployment on Azure Devops using Continous Deployment but i need exclude a file from the repository (i cant change the repository) then create a deployment in IIS.

I have a WebService file in the repository but i cant ignore or delete it from git. I need to use Azure Devops to ignore it then make a continuous deployment.

Comment: When publishing artifacts from your build stage, you can use a `.artifactignore` file to control what files are published. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops

Comment: The code will be checked out to pipeline agent for deployment. If you are not able to change the repository, you can delete the file with a pipeline task(powershell, bash..etc) before your deployment task.

Comment: @DanielMann you should post that as an Answer; I'd vote for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task [Delete Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops), as covered below:

```
# Delete files
# Delete folders, or files matching a pattern
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  inputs:
    #SourceFolder: # Optional
    #Contents: 'myFileShare' 
    #RemoveSourceFolder: # Optional
```

The input source folder can be folder `$(rootFolder)` or `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

I've had a similar problem and solved it this way. Especially `.git` or `.vsfolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approch is also to use .artifactsignore. By including this file you can describe which files you want to ignore before building the artifacts package. The tricky part here is correct placing of the file.
Where you save the .artifactignore file depends which path you have specified for the publish pipeline artifact task in your pipeline definition.
Here is good example which helped me to use it:
https://www.jfe.cloud/control-pipeline-artifacts-with-artifactignore-file/